# How to change where VSC is interpreting and importing its library from?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to "from typing import final" which I read online that it can only be used in python 3.8 or higher.
I installed python 3.10 and changed the interpreter to python3.10. However, when I tried to run my program, it still says that there's an import error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIAnY.png)

Question is how do I change the settings so that it imports from python310 instead of python37

Comment: How did you run your program?